# Failed run flutter app on iOS Simulator on MacOS

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

I'm a beginner in flutter , I'm using android studio to create my flutter app and I need some plugins in pubspec.yaml file!

The is running without problem, But when I added cloud_firestore, firebase_auth, firebase_storage , ImagePicker and fluttertoast I get an error !

This is the error:

```
** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳

/Users/Mr.3bd/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.4.4+2/darwin/Classes/FLTFirebaseCorePlugin.m:6:9: fatal error: 'UserAgent.h' file not found
#import "UserAgent.h"
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
note: Using new build system
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description

warning: Mapping architecture armv7 to i386. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform.(in target 'image_picker' from project 'Pods')
warning: Mapping architecture arm64 to x86_64. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target 'image_picker' from project 'Pods')
warning: There are no architectures to compile for because the VALID_ARCHS build setting is an empty list. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
In file included from /Users/Mr.3bd/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.m:26:
/Users/Mr.3bd/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite-1.2.1/ios/Classes/SqflitePlugin.m:2:9: warning: non-portable path to file '<fmdb/FMDB.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
#import <FMDB/FMDB.h>
```

my pubspec.yaml file:

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_auth: ^0.12.0
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.0
  firebase_storage: ^3.1.0
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.4+6
  flutter_offline: ^0.3.0
  provider: ^3.1.0
  simple_animations: ^1.1.3
  page_transition: ^1.1.4
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  gradient_app_bar: ^0.0.1
  fluttertoast: ^3.1.1
  flutter_spinkit: ^4.0.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.3
  rflutter_alert: ^1.0.3
  url_launcher: ^4.1.0
  flutter_speed_dial: ^1.2.5
  image_picker: ^0.6.3+1
  file_picker: ^1.4.3+2
  validators: ^2.0.0+1
  dio: ^3.0.8
  flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer: ^1.0.7
```

Can anyone help me and update the plugins versions to compatible versions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [github issue 2084](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2084)
and it seems like many people  are experiencing the same.One of the qouted solution is rolling back to older verisons of firebase dependencies .dont forget to remove the `^`  before the version -- because you don't want to accept the newer version; and you may need to `flutter clean` too before building.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently faced this type of issue in my projects but no solution works

Try the above setting and then after it will work

> Go to Xcode -> Select Project -> Build Settings -> Find "Excluded
> Architectures" -> Add "Any iOS Simulator SDK" -> and give value
> `arm64` for `debug` only

Clear Derived data + clean build folder and run the app

Please find snap for more clarification

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me:

```
flutter clean

flutter build ios
```

(`pod install`) If Needed

Answer (score 0):

Xcode's output:
↳

> /Users/pictuscode/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.4.4+2/darwin/Classes/FLTFirebaseCorePlugin.m:6:9: fatal error: 'UserAgent.h' file not found

I resolved the error by removing the  `^`.

Replacing `firebase_core: ^0.4.4+2`

with `firebase_core: 0.4.4` worked